# oledbConn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#

In MVC Application While Connect with Excel gives an error 
I just create a connection with excel and when try to open it's give error

> oledbConn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException

```
 public DataTable Read(string filePath)
        {
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower();
            string connString = string.Empty;
            if (extension.Trim() == ".xls")
            {

                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";

            }
            else if (extension.Trim() == ".xlsx")
            {
                //connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                //connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
            }
            connString = string.Format(connString, filePath);

            var dataTable = ConvertXSLXtoDataTable(filePath, connString);
            return dataTable;
        }
        DataTable ConvertXSLXtoDataTable(string strFilePath, string connString)
        {
            OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {

               oledbConn.Open();
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn))
                {
                    OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                    oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    oleda.Fill(ds);

                    dt = ds.Tables[0];
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {

                oledbConn.Close();
            }

            return dt;

        }
```

Comment: Can you show what `filePath` contains? Is that points to Excel file stored in local or remote machine? Please explain by including exception stack trace and supporting details.

Comment: What is the value of `filePath`? And please provide the full error including the stackTrace. Do you test this on your development machine or a different computer? Does this work on some computers or not at all? Does the code work when you execute it in a console application instead of an MVC project? Can you open the file in Excel successfully? Are you sure the file is not currently opened by any other process on the computer?